# How to loop through s3 bucket starting at a specific object with boto3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a large amount of objects in an s3 bucket (10 million +). I began looping through them and processing each but my process got interrupted halfway. I'd like to know if it's possible to restart the loop at a specific object. For example, I would start at the object that has the key "test.jpeg". I really would rather not start the entire process over.

Here is what I have for looping.

```
for bucket_obj in bucket.objects.filter():
    print bucket_obj.key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can utlize `marker` property of `filter` function. You can start your loop from the desired `marker`. 
If you know where your loop is failing then you can use `getMarker` there and start the loop again by using that value. Here is an example.

```
bucket.listObjects({Prefix: '2015-02', Marker: '2015-02-23-00:00:00'}, callback);
```

Alternatively, like a bad practice, you can store all the object in a `list` or `dict`. Mark them visited every time you loop through it and if loop fails then only loop objects which are not visited. This method can take up so much memory as you have millions of objects.

Comment: Note: this may produce incorrect results if objects have been added to the S3 bucket between the two list calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
for bucket_obj in bucket.objects.filter(Marker="test.jpg"):
    print bucket_obj.key
```